# How to run code depending on whether its running on live website or localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, heroku, https

I'm new to coding. I have a node.js application which I have deployed using "Heroku.com". I want to use a custom domain for the application as well as having SSL active using the custom domain. When the application uses the default domain given by Heroku, SSL is automatically in place, however if I want SSL to work when I use a custom domain, I have to include the following code in my app.js file in order for SSL to work:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
if (req.header('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https')
    res.redirect(`https://${req.header('host')}${req.url}`)
else
    next()
```

});

This works fine, however when I am maintaining my app locally (in VS Code) and use localhost:3000 for testing purposes I have to comment out the code above in order to be able to view the app using locahost because of something to do with localhost not working with HTTPS.

So my question is, is there a code (if statement or something of the like) that will run that code if its being used in a live environment or to not run if its being used in localhost. This is mainly so I don't have to continue to comment out the code before and after deployment and testing.

If you have any other advice or better solutions for this kind of thing I would appreciate it.

Cheers,
Sam

Comment: there are two things here. SSL certificate on your deployment site and SSL on your localhost. They are two completely separate things. I am not a Heroku guy (more into Azure) but I think Heroku is taking care of your SSL stuff automatically since they manage the whole thing. Localhost, managed by you, obviously does not have SSL setup. Try to find out how to setup SSL on localhost, which should be your actual way forward.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for this, Heroku does set up SSL automatically if you use the default domain name they give you for your web application. However you point a custom domain name to Heroku then I need to add the code to my app mentioned above in order to get the SSL to work as it should. Is it usual to have SSL set up on locahost for testing purposes?

Comment: when i working locally, I usually dont worry about too much about SSL setup. sometimes, the SSL is already setup by the framework i am using (for example, visual studio automatically runs everything in SSL and even adds certificates on its own for local testing). But, otherwise, unless i am testing SSL specifically, I have never used it. So, if your testing includes features depending on something being SSL, then, yes, you should considering setting it up. if not, then, no, i would not worry too much about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the concept of **environment variables** to differentiate between the production enviroment (live website on heroku) and the development environment (localhost). Specifically, you can set an environment variable `NODE_ENV` (just a popular naming convention, nothing in-built) to a value that can be used inside your code logic to perform actions based on the environment.

You can access the value by writing

```js
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

*Note:* You have to set the environment variable first, otherwise `process.env.NODE_ENV` is just going to be `undefined`.

**How to set the environment variables?**

There are a couple of ways, like having a `.env` file, passing through CLI, etc. I'll show you a quick way. While running your server on localhost, write this,

```sh
NODE_ENV=development node server.js
```

Now, inside your `server.js`, you can do something like

```js
// If NODE_ENV is undefined, assume production
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (env === 'production' && req.header('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https') {
    res.redirect(`https://${req.header('host')}${req.url}`)
  }
  else {
    next()
  }
})
```

You can have as many environments as you like (development, testing, production, staging, etc.) Also check out [dotenv module](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

Answer (score 0):

## [Edit]

Create folder called config inside add settings.js

```
package.json
app.js
--config    // Will hold your configuration settings
----settings.js     // Your settings
```

In settings.js

```
const settings = {
    development: {
        // Developpment configuration settings
        email: 'development@gmail.com'
    },
    staging: {
        // staging settings
        email: 'staging@gmail.com'
    },
    production: {
        // Production configuration settings
        email: 'production@gmail.com'
    },
}

const getSettings = () => {
    if (!process.env.NODE_ENV) return settings.development
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') return settings.staging
    return settings.production
}

module.exports = getSettings()
```

what is proccess.env.NODE_ENV? It's an enviroment variable which if you didn't declare will return undefined and you can make it's variable different by setting it from the terminal

When you go to development try to run this command in the hoster terminal

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

DON'T RUN THIS IN YOUR LOCAL TERMINAL, try to ask your web hosters how to run a command in their command line to store environment variable

for heroku: heroku run export process.env.NODE_ENV

DON'T WRITE ANY SENSITIVE DATA THERE! store them in environment variables too

Also for the port you would want to do something like this in your app.js

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
```